# HIVE: how to insert data into column with datatype MAP (string:Array<INT>)

Tags: hive

I have a table CLASS1 as shown mentioned below

```
 hive> select * from class1;
 OK
 NULL   student_name    NULL    NULL    NULL
 5  david   60  70  80
 5  reena   55  40  80
 7  joseph  66  75  89
 Time taken: 0.659 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
 hive> desc class1;
 OK
 class                  tinyint                                     
 student_name           varchar(30)                                 
 marks_english          int                                         
 marks_maths            int                                         
 marks_science          int                                         
 Time taken: 0.553 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

Now i wanted to insert this data in below format into a new table

```
    Class     name_marks
    5   {david:[60,70,80]}
    5   {reena:[55,40,80]}
    7   {joseph:[66,75,89]}
```

Can someone tell me how to create a new table and insert the data in the desired format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
create table new_table as
select class
     , MAP(student_name, ARRAY(marks_english, marks_maths, marks_science) as name_marks
  from old_table;
```